# If we were to ¨lasso¨ a photon so that it spun around a point, would it take on different characteristics or look look like other particles?

Tags: photons

If we were to take a photon and have it go around a single point would it still look like a photon or would it look like a different particle/have different characteristics?

Comment: I am quite sorry sir but I think your question isn't clear. What do you mean to lasso a photon? How do you do such thing?

Answer (score 2):

You are describing the [photon sphere](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Photon_sphere#Photon_orbits_around_a_Kerr_black_hole) around a black hole:

> A photon sphere is a spherical region of space where gravity is strong enough that photons are forced to travel in orbits. The radius of the photon sphere, which is also the lower bound for any stable orbit, is for a Schwarzschild black hole:

$r=3GM/c^2$

> where G is the gravitational constant, M is the black hole mass, and c is the speed of light in vacuum

The photon is an elementary particle of zero mass, spin + or -1 in its direction of motion, and energy= $hν$ . No changes in its "character" .

> As photons approach the event horizon of a black hole, those with the appropriate energy avoid being pulled into the black hole by traveling in a nearly tangential direction known as an exit cone. A photon on the boundary of this cone does not possess the energy to escape the gravity well of the black hole. Instead, it orbits the black hole.

Comment: IMHO this is a good and interesting question.  I think the OP is asking if a single photon would act like a particle if confined to a small region- e.g., by a nano-sized black hole.  In this case the "lasso" would be the gravitational force of the black hole.  I think it would be a very interesting system: certainly quantized.  Haven't thought it through, but perhaps it could only work for certain photon energies and certain black hole masses.  If toroidal or mobius strip type topologies were allowed, it could get even more interesting.

Comment: Exactly what I am asking